# Adding cutom option to bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, bootstrap-modal

I am using bootstrap modals in my application.
In here we have modal options like windowClass, Keyboard, etc.
I want to know whether we can add our own custom options in here like 'preventModalClose', 'ABC', etc.

Comment: question too vague. Kindly add respective code

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the source code of [bootstrap UI](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap) (I suppose you are using it because of the `angularjs` tag).

For example, go to the source file of [`modal.js`](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal.js). Go to Line 99, you will find that the option `windowClass` works simply by:

```
element.addClass(attrs.windowClass || '');
```

Say, you want to add a customized option like `preventModalClose`, just modify the function `scope.close` in Line 102:

```
scope.close = function (evt) {
    if (attrs.preventModalClose) {
        return;
    } 
    // The original logic.
}
```

**Start reading the source code of them, they are just Angular directives or even plain JavaScript.**